# Como se ajusta el tamaño del ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

probe con el config.js pero no no se cambia y la verdad en todos los post dicen eso no se si estoy haciendo algo mal

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.language = 'fr';
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
 // misc options 
  config.width= 45;

 config.height = 45;
 };
```

que es el config.js

Comment: Ya revisaste la documentación ?

Comment: si ya la revise y dice lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Fué una simple busqueda en `Google` y darse cuenta que los valores **deben ser números naturales concretos, es decir con medidas,** como `px, vw, etc`

Comment: pues no no sirve pero ya no lo necesito gracias